# Spring @Bean - creation of Spring Bean depends on service class name

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use Spring 4.2.8 and I do have the service class below. If this class has the name **ScheduleEmailCreateAndSendServiceImpl** than everything works fine (method generalEmailMessage is invoked at start time in order to create the Spring Bean)
If I rename this class to **EmailCreateAndSendServiceImpl** than method generalEmailMessage will not be invoked at start time - does anyone know why?

```
@Service("emailCreateAndSendService")
public class ScheduleEmailCreateAndSendServiceImpl extends AbstractService 
implements EmailService {

protected EmailMessage generalMessage;

@Override
public void createAndSendMessage(String receiver, boolean emailActive, Object[] values) throws BusinessException {
    // create and send email
}

@Bean
public EmailMessage generalEmailMessage() {
    this.generalMessage = new GeneralEmailInformationMessage();
    return generalMessage;
}
```

}

[EDIT]

with this code it is the same

```
@Configuration
public @Data class ScheduleGeneralEmailConfiguration {

protected EmailMessage generalMessage;

public ScheduleGeneralEmailConfiguration() {
    System.out.println("asdf");
}

@Bean
public EmailMessage generalEmailMessage() {
    this.generalMessage = new GeneralEmailInformationMessage();
    return generalMessage;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you should annotate your class with `@Configuration` annotation

Comment: Why is the message a bean? And why do you declare a bean in a service rather than in a `@Configuration`?

Comment: You are mixing things up a bit. The `@Service` annotation is used for component scanning. So Spring creates a bean with name `emailCreateAndSendService` of class `ScheduleEmailCreateAndSendServiceImpl`. The `@Bean` annotation should be used in `@Configuration` annoted class to create beans "manually".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Bean` annotated methods should be in `@Configuration` annotated class.

You can also put the `@Bean` annotated methods in the main class of the Spring Boot application annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations.

Make sure your `@Configuration` annotated class is placed in the same package or sub package of the Spring Boot Application class